# Metasploit Framework .go module can't be loaded

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

This is my first post, so I might get the format wrong.. Anyway, after searching for a solution online (which I could not find), I resorted to asking here.

Upon launching my msfconsole a few days ago, I started getting all of these warnings/errors which were not showing before.

```
$ sudo msfconsole                                 
[!] The following modules could not be loaded!..\
[!]     /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/msmail/host_id.go
[!]     /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/msmail/exchange_enum.go
[!]     /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/msmail/onprem_enum.go
[!] Please see /root/.msf4/logs/framework.log for details.
```

metasploit v6.0.31-dev

I could not find any solution to this .go module loading issue. I might have screwed something over some time ago, but my last VM snapshot is just too far away.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

just install go in your kali:

```sh
sudo apt install gccgo-go
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem.
But, since the error message clearly ask me to check error log file, actually there is clear solution too.

> [!] Please see /root/.msf4/logs/framework.log for details.

> [09/05/2021 22:29:56] [e(0)] core: /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/msmail/onprem_enum.go failed to load - LoadError Failed to execute external Go module. Please ensure you have Go installed on your environment.

And after the Go installation, the problem is solved.
Therefore, the solutions is that you just need to install Go on your machine.